# What is the general term for tree-dwelling animals?

Tags: zoology

Many different types of animals live primarily in trees, from birds to monkeys and beyond.

Is there a general term that I can use to refer to all of them?

The closest I've been able to come is "arboreal", and I'm not sure that that particular term is appropriate for the broad range of animals encompassed by the casual usage of "tree-dwelling."

Comment: What do you mean by "the casual usage"? [Dictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Arboreal+animal) seems to make the meanings rather explicit and clear. An animal that lives in or amongst trees is arboreal.

Comment: *Arboreal* is indeed the correct term to use.